# Get the values from List<EntityClass>

Tags: c#, list

I'm populating my `List` like this:

```
public List<Functions> ListFunctions(int proj)
   {
      List<Functions> lFunctions = new List<Functions>();
      try
         {
            string sql = "SELECT id, description FROM functios WHERE project = @project ORDER BY description ASC";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@project", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = proj;

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = _dal.ExecutaReader(cmd))
               {
                  while (reader.Read())
                     {
                        lFunctions.Add(new Function
                          {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                            Descripton = reader["description"].ToString()
                          });
                      }
                }
            return lFunction;
         }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

How may I loop through the list and get those values now ? The `Description` and the `ID`

I'd like to know a way to get exactly the fieldName, like:

```
string name = ListFunction["FieldName"].ToString()
```

Comment: I'm not familliar with all the functions you're calling.. But I see no reason why you can't use foreach.

Comment: How about using a `foreach`-loop?

Comment: @DominicKexel I thought about `ForEach` I just do not know `HOW` to use the foreach to get the exactly value, you know ? Get the value of `Description` and the `ID`

Comment: @Jordy Agree... I just do not know exatcly the way to use the `foreach`loop with `list<T>`.

Comment: @Ghaleon try to google on `msdn foreach loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just enumerate over the returned list. For example:

```
var functions=ListFunctions(0); // For example
foreach(var function in functions)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}",function.ID, function.Description);
}
```

Comment: What If I had more than 2 fields, how may I loop throught using the `fieldName` ? Like `string descrip = listFunction["fieldName"]`

Comment: @Ghleon: You'd have to extract them into a Dictionary<string,object> and access them via a field name lookup.